# Error with user click on cancel on file upload dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, dialog

i have a input type file like this:

```
<div class="custom-file btn-file">
    <input height="35px" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="i_file_1" name="i_file[]" accept="application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
</div>
```

i handle onchange event to render the file in a modal; but i have an issues when user have selected a file that is in the input, and try to change it but being once in the dialog click on cancel it send error.

```
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function(evt) {
var size = this.files[0].size;
console.log(size);
});
```

This error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (func.js?20180702235402:11)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?20180702235402:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js?20180702235402:3)
(anonymous) @ func.js?20180702235402:11
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?20180702235402:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js?20180702235402:3
```

```js
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function(evt) {
  var size = this.files[0].size;
  console.log(size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-file btn-file">
  <input height="35px" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="i_file_1" name="i_file[]" accept="application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me.  I choose a file and it console logged 85447.

Comment: @Taplar work when you select a file. after that i you click and re open the dialog and click on cancel instead of select other file send error.

Comment: Ok, so then you just need to perform an if statement to make sure that the length of the files array is > 0.  ezpz

Comment: Not sure why this only happens when at least one file is selected - if you haven't selected anything no error is thrown!
Could this be an implementation thing of the file input element - OS maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if you have `files` object or not. if so then get the size. otherwise fallback to 0 or something like that

```js
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function(evt) {
  var size = this.files[0] ? this.files[0].size : 0;
  console.log(`size ${size}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-file btn-file">
  <input height="35px" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="i_file_1" name="i_file[]" accept="application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
</div>
```